# Picasso Library Exception crashes

Tags: android, image, crash, picasso, crash-reports

I have problem with Picasso, I got crashes:

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.squareup.picasso.PicassoExecutorService$PicassoFutureTask@41a39a38 rejected from com.squareup.picasso.PicassoExecutorService@41acc1d0[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1967)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:782)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1303)
   at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoExecutorService.submit(PicassoExecutorService.java:88)
   at com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.performSubmit(Dispatcher.java:202)
   at com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.performSubmit(Dispatcher.java:175)
   at com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher$DispatcherHandler.handleMessage(Dispatcher.java:482)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

This is how I create Picasso in onResume():

```
    final Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    builder.indicatorsEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
    builder.defaultBitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    final long cacheSize = (long) (getAvailableRam() * 0.5F);

    builder.memoryCache(new LruCache((int) cacheSize));
    builder.listener(_listener);
    _picasso = builder.build();
```

and in onPause():

```
    if (_picasso != null) {
        _picasso.shutdown();
        _picasso = null;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is in shutdown. I suggest to cancel all tasks before and then shutdown picasso :)

Checkout this: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/329

**Simple fast solution.**

Use single instance for picasso

```
  /** Stops this instance from accepting further requests. */
  public void shutdown() {
    if (this == singleton) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Default singleton instance cannot be shutdown.");
    }
    if (shutdown) {
      return;
    }
    cache.clear();
    cleanupThread.shutdown();
    stats.shutdown();
    dispatcher.shutdown();
    for (DeferredRequestCreator deferredRequestCreator : targetToDeferredRequestCreator.values()) {
      deferredRequestCreator.cancel();
    }
    targetToDeferredRequestCreator.clear();
    shutdown = true;
  }
```

Check:

```
  public void cancelTag(Object tag) {
    checkMain();
    if (tag == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot cancel requests with null tag.");
    }

    List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>(targetToAction.values());
    //noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
    for (int i = 0, n = actions.size(); i < n; i++) {
      Action action = actions.get(i);
      if (tag.equals(action.getTag())) {
        cancelExistingRequest(action.getTarget());
      }
    }

    List<DeferredRequestCreator> deferredRequestCreators =
        new ArrayList<DeferredRequestCreator>(targetToDeferredRequestCreator.values());
    //noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
    for (int i = 0, n = deferredRequestCreators.size(); i < n; i++) {
      DeferredRequestCreator deferredRequestCreator = deferredRequestCreators.get(i);
      if (tag.equals(deferredRequestCreator.getTag())) {
        deferredRequestCreator.cancel();
      }
    }
  }
```